# Execution failed for task ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to use the `ionic capacitor run android` commant to deploy my React app build using Ionic and Capacitor and having this error:

`Execution failed for task ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugKotlin'`

[image]

I've seen some other answers on Stackoverflow but there wasn't any solid solitions, any ideas?